# Facebook error require_once

Tags: php, android, facebook, session, facebook-graph-api

What is causing this error?

```
 error: Fatal error: use: Not yet supported. Please use include_once() or 
 require_once() in /home/free/byl.cz/d/docasne/root/www/index.php on line 7
```

**code here**: http://paste.org/72519

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using. Facebook PHP SDK v4 needs PHP 5.4

Comment: please share some relevant code in post as link may get lost.